# error during Adding data through CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

while I am adding details in database through CSV file I am getting error-
`Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)` . I have checked database username and password. even if I add product one by one(without csv) it is workin fine. It means my database connectivity is correct. Do I need to make some change in my database hosting accoun or some code error?

```
connect_db(); // MYSQL connection settings


    $sql="LOAD DATA 
    INFILE '$file_name' INTO TABLE tbl_product 
    IELDS TERMINATED BY \"\t\" 
    LINES TERMINATED BY \"\n\" 
    ( cat_id, pd_name, pd_description, pd_price, pd_qty, pd_image, pd_thumbnail, pd_date, pd_last_update, tax)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your MySQL user doesn't have the correct permissions

Try executing this and then flush

```
grant file on *.* to user@host identified by 'password';
```

Adding [ref link](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?30,12298,12298#msg-12298)

Answer (score 1):

You might not have FILE permissions required in order to load a file.  Documentation for the LOAD DATA INFILE statement states:

> For security reasons, when reading
>   text files located on the server, the
>   files must either reside in the
>   database directory or be readable by
>   all. Also, to use LOAD DATA INFILE on
>   server files, you must have the FILE
>   privilege. See Section 5.4.1,
>   “Privileges Provided by MySQL”. For
>   non-LOCAL load operations, if the
>   secure_file_priv system variable is
>   set to a nonempty directory name, the
>   file to be loaded must be located in
>   that directory.